# I use a method from a superclass, fragmentActivity, but eclipse says the method can't be found

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Before, when I hovered over the FragmentActivity, I would get "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found." I went to the location of the android-support-v4.jar in my package and imported the source and javadoc and got rid of that, but eclipse still cannot find the method in the superclass when I try to use it or override it.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // if the session is already open,
            // try to show the selection fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else {
            // otherwise present the splash screen
            // and ask the person to login.
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: which method are you trying to access?

Comment: onResumeFragments(), it says that it is undefined for the type FragmentActivity. However, when I override other methods from FragmentActivity, there are no errors.

Comment: can you add your code in question

Comment: @OjembaWakiki you should call this method on `Activity`, not on `FragmentActivity`. Try looking for available override methods in Eclipse. Source: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/757

Comment: I have this method in SherlockFragmentActivity working fine

Comment: @MocialovBoris, how do I call the method on Activity? Thanks